# Why does re.sub return None?

Tags: python, regex

I have seen this function in some code on github, I think its aim is to clean up these signs from the input text, but I do not know why every string that is fed into this the output becomes None. Any help is appreciated.

```
def clean(self, text):
    text = re.sub('[^\w\s\d\'\-\"]','', text)
    text = text.lower()
```

Comment: Please fix your python indentation. Also, how is the output being produced? Please include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Because the function does not return anything.

Comment: Thanks that's right. Do you know what exactly re.sub do here? I have not seen in other examples of re.sub that [ ] be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python functions that lack an explicit `return` statement implicilty return `None`. Your `clean` function does not have a return statement. You could try adding `return text`.

Comment: Thank you so much that was right. Do you know what exactly re.sub do here? I have not seen in other examples of re.sub that [ ] be used.

Comment: @parvaneh `sub` means "substitution". It's replacing instances of the regex pattern in the text with `''`(nothing). In this case it's removing all characters not in the specified class.

Comment: @parvaneh `[^bar]` matches any character except `b`, `a`, or `r`, for example. The `[]` designates a set, and `[^]` its negation. Some of the `\ ` forms also represent sets of characters. See the `re` module documentation.